# Simplified lines disappear in smaller zoom levels in ArcGIS JavaScript v.4.14 map

Tags: leaflet, line, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, simplify

I have a GraphicsLayer on ArcGIS js map with many lines of varying lengths (1 to 200m).
However, in smaller zoom levels the short lines disappear. For example, in the images below the red lines are visible in the larger zoom level and then they are no longer visible when zoomed out:

[image: ArcGIS zoomed in]

ArcGIS zoomed in

[image: ArcsGIS zoomed out]

ArcGIS zoomed out

Having the same layer on Leaflet does not have this effect and the short lines appear like points:

[image: Leaflet zoomed out]

Leaflet zoomed out

Here is the code:

```
    this.simpleLineSymbolLeft = new SimpleLineSymbol({
        type: "simple-line",
        color: [247, 45, 45],
        width: 5,
        style: "solid"
    });

let graphic = new Graphic({
            geometry: polyline,
            symbol: this.simpleLineSymbolLeft,
            attributes: properties
        })
```

I assume this is a simplification effect, based on which very short line, instead of being collapsed into points, they are turned off. Is there a way to tweak this so that the short lines will not disappear?

Comment: It would be nice to see the code relative to the styling of the features in question.

Comment: I updated the question with some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume this is a simplification effect, based on which very short
>   line, instead of being collapsed into points, they are turned off.

Correct, the ArcGIS API for JavaScript does not draw lines when they
are shorter than a pixel. That's why they "disappear" as you zoom
out.

> Is there a way to tweak this so that the short lines will not disappear?

I don't think there's a way to automatically make them not disappear.  What you could do as a workaround is adding all the nodes as points, since the points wouldn't disappear when zooming out.

Comment: I was afraid there was no automatic solution -  I will try out your workaround!